# Device Doesn't Exist In Current Context Xamarin Android Development

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am currently developing an Android App in Xamarin Native Android. I need to open an email URL once a button is pressed however I am getting the error.

"CS0103  C# The name 'Device' does not exist in the current context"

This is my code. When i click to try to import anything it suggests i import the Bluetooth class unsurprisingly this didn't work.

```
        Email.Click += delegate {
            Device.OpenUri(new Uri("mailto:joe@test.com"));
        };
```

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks 
Joe

Comment: Device is a static class in the Xamarin.Forms namespace.  Are you using Xamarin Forms?

Comment: Hello Jason, I am not using Xamarin forms.

Answer (score 1):

In Android, you would do this to [open a URL](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/fundamentals/intent/open_a_webpage_in_the_browser_application/)

```
intent.button.Click += delegate {
       var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse ("http://www.xamarin.com");
       var intent = new Intent (Intent.ActionView, uri);
       StartActivity (intent);
};
```

Comment: How would i open the default email client? with a pre-populated email address?

Comment: Thanks Jason with a bit of tinkering I got it working. I'm too new for my vote to register but i voted positively for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

My Solution

```
         Email.Click += delegate {
            Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ActionSend);
            email.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraEmail, "Test@gmail.com");
            email.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraSubject, "Subject Area");
            email.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraText, "Subject");
            email.SetType("messsage/rfc822");
            StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(email, "Send Email Via"));

        };
```